# Uninstalling Qt5

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, uninstall, qt

I wanted to uninstall Qt and I ran this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove qt5-default
```

and I got this answer :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'qt5-default' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove, and 36 not upgraded.
```

but qt5 and its dependencies Software ( assistant, chooser, creator, ....) are still in my dash and they can be run...

what is the solution to uninstall that?
why is this happening?

tnx :)

Comment: We don't know your OS & release, nor what software that you have installed that uses the Q toolkit (version 5). You also provided an `apt` command, but may have installed Qt in other methods, but we don't know your release (or how likely that is)  FYI:   I'm running a Qt5 based desktop myself, and don't have the package `qt5-default` installed (it's not a dependency of my Qt5 desktop, nor of any software I use actually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list installed packages matching `qt5` like this:

```
apt list --installed | grep "qt5"
```

Then you can uninstall the packages that match